# Do we need @Transactional only for write methods in spring data jpa?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactions

For example, I have two repository methods such as

```java
@Query("select * from person        where name  = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
Person findPersonByName(String name);
```

```java
@Modifying 
@Query("delete from person where id  = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
int deletePersonById(Long id);
```

Here the first method works fine and returns an entity person.

But second method throws `TransactionRequiredException`.

As per the docs, `CrudRepository` methods are by default transactional.

I understand from this statement that those methods of `Repository` and `CrudRepository` are marked `@Transactional` in proxy classes implementing repositories, and custom query methods are NOT transactional.

If this is the case, don't we need transactional annotation on my first method? How does it work without transactional?

Why second method works only if I  include transactional annotation?

I tried adding transactional annotation on second method and it works.

But why first method doesn't need this annotation and why first one works even without explicitly applied transactional annotation?

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to the [specification of the `EntityManager`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html#a1066). It basically requires a transaction for writing operations (`merge`, `persist`, `delete`) and does not need one for reading operations.